# Bar plot transition does not work with D3.js v4

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a code for creating a bar plot and updating it every certain amount of time.
The code works fine while I am using `d3.v3.min.js` but when I am using `d3.v4.min.js` the code does not run. 
The use of `d3.v4.min.js` is essential for other parts of the code.
Here is the complete example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body style='background-color:lightgray'>
        <div id="chart" style='width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>

        <script>
      var width = 400, height = 350;
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, left: 40, bottom: 20};
var categoryIndent = 4*15 + 5, defaultBarWidth = 2000;

        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,defaultBarWidth])
        .range([0,width]);
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1, 0);

     updateBarPlot(); 

      function updateBarPlot(){ 
        var Cn0 = [{"key" : 2, "value" : Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}, {"key" : 5, "value" : Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}, {"key" : 10, "value" : Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}];

    y.domain(Cn0.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.value - a.value;
      }).map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    var barmax = d3.max(Cn0, function(e) {
        return e.value;
      });
    x.domain([0,barmax]);

    var chartRow = svg.selectAll("g.chartRow")
        .data(Cn0, function(d){ return d.key});

    var newRow = chartRow
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "chartRow")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + margin.top + margin.bottom + ")");

    newRow.insert("rect")
        .attr("class","bar")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("opacity",0)
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value);})
        .style("fill","steelblue" );

    newRow.append("text")
        .attr("class","label")
        .attr("y", y.rangeBand()/2)
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("opacity",0)
        .attr("dy",".35em")
        .attr("dx","0.5em")
        .attr("fill","white")
        .text(function(d){return d.value;});

    newRow.append("text")
        .attr("class","category")
        .attr("text-overflow","ellipsis")
        .attr("y", y.rangeBand()/2)
        .attr("x",categoryIndent)
        .attr("opacity",0)
        .attr("dy",".35em")
        .attr("dx","0.5em")
        .attr("fill","white")
        .text(function(d){return "G" + d.key});

    chartRow.select(".bar").transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value);})
        .attr("opacity",1);

    chartRow.select(".label").transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .tween("text", function(d) { 
            var i = d3.interpolate(+this.textContent.replace(/\,/g,''), +d.value);
            return function(t) {
                this.textContent = Math.round(i(t));
            };
        });

    chartRow.select(".category").transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("opacity",1);

    chartRow.exit().transition()
        .style("opacity","0")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .remove();

    var delay = function(d, i) { return 200 + i * 30; };

    chartRow.transition()
        .delay(delay)
        .duration(900)
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(0," + y(d.key) + ")"; });

     setTimeout(updateBarPlot, 1000);   

}
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I update the value of the bar upon each transition. When i am trying to use the `d3.v4.min.js` that label value stops updating and it stuck on the first value that was in there the first time.
What could be the issue and how could this issue be fixed?

In the main code in the `<head>` i import both d3 versions like this:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to fix it? Any ideas?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you changing your v3 code to v4? [Here is a list of all changes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40)

Comment: Thank you.  So both versions can not exist together in the same code correct?

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure, I believe that is true. If you aren't using a library that explicitly requires v3 I would use v4/5

Comment: ok. ill look into that.